# How to apply themes for an exact view?

Tags: android, view, styles, themes

For example when I define a style tag in XML, all views of all types get that theme. Is there any solution to difference between styles for view types? here is some code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="buttonTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:drawableLeft">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    </style>

    <style name="textTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103894/overriding-referenced-style-attributes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there's a small confusion in terms between a style and a theme.  You are talking about defining custom styles for a widget in your application.  A Theme is a collection of these styles applied globally to an Activity or Application.  The custom styles you have created for a button and text view can be applied to a new custom theme so all buttons and text items share the same attributes.

I think what you are looking for is something more like this.

```
<style name="ApplicationTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="textAppearance">@style/MyTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:drawableLeft">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextAppearance" parent="android:TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

Here, we have created two new styles (one for the button appearance and one for default text appearance), and then applied those as attributes in a new custom theme.  You can now apply this theme in your manifest or in View constructors by referencing `@style/ApplicationTheme` or `R.style.ApplicationTheme`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding the attribute `android:theme=""` to the specific activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Example:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```